# Is it possible to upload 2 different sets of files to 2 different locations in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a Maven project, in whose `mvn install` phase a certain JAR is generated and uploaded via FTP to a server.

In the same project there is a directory with static HTML and image files (that's the HTML client of the server JAR), which I want to upload to a web server whenever the server JAR is updated. The existing upload routine must be preserved.

Is it possible to do this (2 completely different sets of files are uploaded to different locations in the same phase and `pom.xml`) in Maven? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin with profile:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                   <execution>
                      <phase>install</phase>
                      <goals>
                         <goal>run</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                      <tasks>
                         <echo>Using q.png</echo>
                <copy file="/home/yyy/Desktop/q.png" 
                tofile ="/home/yyy/Desktop/qpk/q.png"/>
            <echo>Using asd.html</echo>
                <copy file="/home/yyy/Desktop/asd.html" 
                tofile ="/home/yyy/Documents/asd.html"/>
                      </tasks>
                      </configuration>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: While this may work, it makes the build non-portable. I would personally advise against this, but rather -- split the project as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's time to split your project into two modules. Have one of the projects contain the webapp stuff (HTML, CSS, JS, etc) and the other -- containing the other code relating to your second case, or have different assemblies as actual separate modules/projects.

Also, the `install` goal is not the one that is (or should be) deploying the files, but rather -- the `deploy` goal.